# Fire Event on Mail sent - Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

It is possible to fire a Event on Mail sent in Laravel using view name as id ? for example :

```
 Event::listener('emails.register', function($mail){});
```

Comment: It doesn't works, I want to execute a script just after a Mail sent.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe event litener with `Event::listen` (not `listener`):

```
Event::listen('emails.register', function($mail){
  // do something with $mail
});
```

then fire the event:

```
// using Facade
Event::fire('emails.register', $mail);

// or resolving dispatcher from the IoC container
App::make('events')->fire('emails.register', $mail);
```